# Azure Logic Apps fail condtion

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, facebook-permissions

I have setting up an Azure logic apps on my azure account that send posts for both Facebook and Twitter based on an condition many days before I had tested my logic apps successful published post but now this issue occurred I have no idea about that.
Many thanks for your help.
[image]

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "GHv4s/FqX8U"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with user permissions in AAD (Azure Active Directory). 
Go to the logic app's
`Access control (IAM) -> View my access`
[image]

In my case I see the following

[image]

but perhaps you have read-only rights. Once you can modify the logic app, you should have sufficient administrative permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more a problem of the user's permissions with which you establish the connection in the LogicApp. check if that profile with which you have established the connection with Facebook has the necessary permissions to perform the actions described in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log out of both Azure / Facebook and re-enter the credentials.

Comment: I did that, I had reentered the credentials but the issue not solved yet.

Comment: what's the exact thing are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a table consisted of (title,details,photo) When an item is created  automatically post on facebook,twitter and linkedin, I have no problem with twitter and linkedin just facebook has this issue although I had used another facebook account. thanks